# Kernel Density Estimation (KDE) in GME (aka Hawth's Tools) Not Working

Tags: r, gis, kernel-density

I've been trying to produce Kernel Density Estimates using the "kde" tool from
Geospatial Modeling Environment ([GME](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/images/SpatialEcologyGME.pdf), see documentation on kde). But I keep getting the following error regardless of valid input:

Code:

```
kde(in="C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\KDE_Scripting_Local\kde.gdb!BB_90sJAN", 
    out="C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\KDE_Scripting_Local\kde.gdb!KDE_BB90sJAN", 
    bandwidth="100000", cellsize=6000, kernel="QUARTIC", 
    ext="C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\KDE_Scripting_Local\kde.gdb!rect_extent");
```

Error message:

> Error: The command text could not be interpreted. Please check the syntax of the command. Error: An important error has occurred. Please include the information below if you submit a query about this error.
>   Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004025A

The most frustrating part is that I had this exact code working last week. I tried restarting, reinstalling GME, copying the input to a new GDB as suggested [here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/35822), subprocesses with PYTHON 2.7. Everything still produces this error with the same HRESULT.

I'm running GME Version 0.7.3.0, ArcGIS For Desktop 10.2.2, R Version 3.1.1, and Python 2.7 on Windows 7. There's not much community support for GME, so any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running that command directly in R (after doing `library(ks)` to load the package that supplies the function `kde()`)? The result of doing that should help you get a better handle on where in the pipeline your error is coming from.

Comment: I have. kde() from ks produces output from an equivalent csv file with no errors. It would be nice to just run these kdes through R directly, but neither this kde from ks, nor any I've found so far, allow for adjusting the _kernel type_. I want to have GAUSSIAN and QUARTIC outputs.

Comment: Assuming that GME is still not open source (I haven't looked into it in 3 or so years), I'd suggest dropping Hawthorne Beyer a line by email to ask him which R functions he uses to implement the QUARTIC kernel option. Best of luck.